# problem with laravel when run composer install

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, git-clone

i have a laravel project on my github. and i recently cloned to my pc but for some reason i got this error:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
```

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   @php artisan package:discover

```
In Compiler.php line 36:

Please provide a valid cache path.


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event 
returned with error code 1
```

I created cache, sessions and framework folder inside storage folder but it does not work.

I also tried many things I read on forums and here on stack but nothing works with me.

i really don't know what's happening.

Comment: Do you have the "vendor" folder? Usually when you get a laravel project from online repositories the "vendor" folder is in .gitignore. You have to install it when you get it locally by "composer update" or "composer install"

Comment: can you run "composer global update" ?

Comment: i tried run this command but the system cant find composer.json. in laravel project folder there is a composer.json. but in composer folder there's not. should i create one?

Comment: The exception was thrown in Compiler.php line 36 because $cachePath is false. You can try trace back the error with debug_backtrace(), see what you can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first run: `composer update`

Create these folders under storage/framework:

- sessions
- views
- cache

and run this below commands:

- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan view:clear

Comment: for some reason, .gitinore was set to ignore a lot of important files to project. but your answer helps me a lot. ty.